# object has no attribute 'visible_device_list'

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to extract faces from pics but in some where I hit this error:

my code:

> config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto #tf.ConfigProto()
>
> config.gpu_options.visible_device_list ='0'

and the error I get:
AttributeError: 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.FieldProperty' object has no attribute 'visible_device_list'

If there is help, I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

just need to add two parentheses!

> config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()